# Generating the base64 of sha256 of a file for Content Security Policy of a web page

Tags: linux, hash, content-security-policy

#### The issue

I have a small private Apache2 web server running on Debian 10 Buster with security on my top list. Right now, I'm struggling with:

How to generate in the Linux terminal the `base64`-encoded `sha256` of my CSS style sheet file `styles.less` for Content Security Policy?

---

#### Getting close

The closest I got was thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128038/how-to-generate-sha256-hash-from-inline-javascript/58977080#comment97007795_55128038) made by [sideshowbarker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/441757/sideshowbarker) with command:

```
cat styles.less | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64
```

So far I only know that this part is ok:

```
cat styles.less | openssl dgst -sha256
```

because the output SHA-256 hash sum equals to ordinary `sha256sum` command, as proved with:

```
$ cat styles.less | openssl dgst -sha256
(stdin)= 0d1095db21ec5177406ed074dadd59d8298f6f4f9ae870bf8d562feeb081ecb1

$ sha256sum styles.less
0d1095db21ec5177406ed074dadd59d8298f6f4f9ae870bf8d562feeb081ecb1  styles.less
```

---

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
```

Any ideas welcome. Will be back shortly, be patient with comment replies, thank you.

---

Getting wrong output:

```
DRCV2yHsUXdAbtB02t1Z2CmPb0+a6HC/jVYv7rCB7LE=
```

Chrome says it shall be (I hope I'm getting the right one):

```
OiTUxy1L7oqoB+m4jFzA6QMKYPBRZqHn9Z33xviiEFI=
```

---

As it might be helpful now, here's [the direct link for that style sheet](https://programyburian.cz/styles.less). Hope we solve it soon.